# Recovering elements of large array with multiple index ranges

Tags: c, arrays, indexing

This is a tricky problem that I have been thinking about for a long time and have yet to see a satisfactory answer anywhere. Lets say I have a large int array of size 10000. I can simply declare it in the following manner:

```
 int main()
{

    int foo[10000];

    int i;
    int n;
    n = sizeof(foo) / sizeof(int);

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        printf("Index %d is %d\n",i,foo[i] );
    }

    return 0;
}
```

It is pretty clear that each index in the array will hold a random assortment of numbers before I formally initialize them:

```
Index 0 is 0
Index 1 is 0
Index 2 is 0
Index 3 is 0
   .
   .
   .
Index 6087 is 0
Index 6088 is 1377050464
Index 6089 is 32767
Index 6090 is 1680893034
   .
   .
   .
Index 9996 is 0
Index 9997 is 0
Index 9998 is 0
Index 9999 is 0
```

Then lets say that I initialize select index ranges of my array with values **that hold a specific value for the program as a whole and must be preserved**, with the goal of passing in those values for subsequent operation to some function:

```
//Call this block 1
foo[0] = 0;
foo[1] = 7;
foo[2] = 99;
foo[3] = 0;

//Call this block 2
foo[9996] = 0;
foo[9997] = 444;
foo[9998] = 2;
foo[9999] = 0;

for (i = 0; i < (What goes here?); i++)
{
    //I must pass in only those values initialized to select indices of foo[] (Blocks 1 and 2 uncorrupted)

    //How to recover those values to pass into foo_func()?

    foo_func(foo[]);
}
```

Some of those values that I initialized `foo[]` with overlap with pre-existing values in the array before formally initializing the array myself. How can I pass in just the indices of the array elements that I initialized, given that there are multiple index ranges? I just can't figure this out. Thanks for any and all help!

EDIT:

I should also mention that the array itself will be read from a .txt file. I just showed the initialization in the code for illustrative purposes.

Comment: Don't pass them at all - use a global const array?

Comment: Well first of all initialize array to zeros int foo[10000]={0}; then do what you want to do(i don't understand what exactly you want to do)

Comment: @MartinJames I neglected to mention this but a global constant array wouldn't work because the array itself would be read from a .txt file so it must be handled dynamically in the code.

Comment: About the edit: plese post *actual code* not "illustrative code".

Answer (score 1):

There's a number of ways you can quickly zero out the memory in the array, either while initializing or after.

For an array on the stack, initialize it with zeros. `{0}` is shorthand for that.

```
int foo[10000] = {0};
```

For an array on the heap, use [`calloc`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_calloc.htm) to allocate memory and initialize it with 0's.

```
int *foo = calloc(10000, sizeof(int));
```

If the array already exists, use [`memset`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_memset.htm) to quickly overwrite all the array's memory with zeros.

```
memset(foo, 0, sizeof(int) * 10000);
```

Now all elements are zero. You can set individual elements to whatever you like one by one. For example...

```
int main() {
    int foo[10] = {0};

    foo[1] = 7;
    foo[2] = 99;
    foo[7] = 444;
    foo[8] = 2;

    for( int i = 0; i < 10; i++ ) {
        printf("%d - %d\n", i, foo[i]);
    }
}
```

That will print...

```
0 - 0
1 - 7
2 - 99
3 - 0
4 - 0
5 - 0
6 - 0
7 - 444
8 - 2
9 - 0
```

---

As a side note, using only a few elements of a large array is a waste of memory. Instead, use a [hash table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table), or if you need ordering, some type of [tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_(data_structure)). These can be difficult to implement correctly, but [a library such as GLib can provide you with good implementations](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-data-types.html).

Comment: This is helpful, but let’s say in addition to the values you initialized, you also initialized foo[9]=0. How can I subsequently pass in just the initialized values into foo_func() (index 1, 2, 7, 8, 9); while leaving out the others? Is this possible?

Comment: @J_code Because an array is just a block of memory, you can't tell the difference between a number you set to 0 and a number you initialized to 0. You *could* use declare some value to be a sentinel, like if your numbers can never be negative use -1. Or if the array is `float` use `NaN`. But there's no way to find the "set" values without slowly iterating through the whole array. It's better to use a more suitable data structure like a hash table or tree.

Answer (score 0):

### Introduction

I'm making a strong assumption on your problem, and it is **sparsness** (a majority of the elements in your array will remain zero).
Under this assumption I would build the array as a **list**. I'm including a sample code, that it is not complete and it is not intended to
be---you should do your own homework :)

The core object is a struct with a pointer to a `begin` element and the size:

```
typedef struct vector {
  size_t size;
  vector_element_t * begin;
} vector_t;
```

each element of the vector has its own index and value and a pointer to the next element in a list:

```
typedef struct vector_element vector_element_t;
struct vector_element {
  int value;
  size_t index;
  vector_element_t *next;
};
```

on this basis we can build a dynamical vector as a list, by dropping a constraint on the ordering (it is not needed, **you can** modify this code
to maintain the ordering), using some simple custom methods:

```
vector_t * vector_init(); // Initialize an empty array
void vector_destroy(vector_t* v); // Destroy the content and the array itself
int vector_get(vector_t *v, size_t index); // Get an element from the array, by searching the index
size_t vector_set(vector_t *v, size_t index, int value); // Set an element at the index
void vector_delete(vector_t *v, size_t index); // Delete an element from the vector
void vector_each(vector_t *v, int(*f)(size_t index, int value)); // Executes a callback for each element of the list
                                                                 // This last function may be the response to your question
```

[Test it online](https://onlinegdb.com/S1a_RFdkQ)

### The main example

This is a main that uses all this methods and prints in console:

```
int callback(size_t index, int value) {
  printf("Vector[%lu] = %d\n", index, value);
  return value;
}

int main() {
  vector_t * vec = vector_init();

  vector_set(vec, 10, 5);
  vector_set(vec, 23, 9);
  vector_set(vec, 1000, 3);

  printf("vector_get(vec, %d) = %d\n", 1000, vector_get(vec, 1000)); // This should print 3
  printf("vector_get(vec, %d) = %d\n", 1, vector_get(vec, 1)); // this should print 0
  printf("size(vec) = %lu\n", vec->size); // this should print 3 (the size of initialized elements)

  vector_each(vec, callback); // Calling the callback on each element of the
                              // array that is initialized, as you asked.

  vector_delete(vec, 23);
  printf("size(vec) = %lu\n", vec->size);
  vector_each(vec, callback); // Calling the callback on each element of the array

  vector_destroy(vec);
  return 0;
}
```

And the output:

```
vector_get(vec, 1000) = 3
vector_get(vec, 1) = 0
size(vec) = 3
Vector[10] = 5
Vector[23] = 9
Vector[1000] = 3
size(vec) = 3
Vector[10] = 5
Vector[1000] = 3
```

The `callback` with the function `vector_each` is something you really should look at.

### Implementations

I'm giving you some trivial implementations for the functions in the introdution. They are not complete,
and **some checks on pointers** should be introduced. I'm leaving that to you. As it is, **this code is not for production and under some circumstances can also overflow**.

The particular part is the search of a specific element in the vector. Every time you tranverse the list,
and this is convenient only and only if you have sparsity (the majority of your index will always return zero).
In this implementation, if you access an index that is not enlisted, you get as a result 0. If you don't want this
you should define an error callback.

#### Initialization and destruction

When we initialize, we allocate the memory for our vector, but with no elements inside, thus `begin` points to `NULL`. When we destroy the vector we have not only to free the vector, but also each element contained.

```
vector_t * vector_init() {
  vector_t * v = (vector_t*)malloc(sizeof(vector_t));
  if (v) {
    v->begin = NULL;
    v->size = 0;
    return v;
  }
  return NULL;
}

void vector_destroy(vector_t *v) {
  if (v) {
    vector_element_t * curr = v->begin;
    if (curr) {
      vector_element_t * next = curr->next;
      while (next) {
        curr = curr->next;
        next = next->next;
        if (curr)
          free(curr);
      }
      if (next)
        free(next);
    }
    free(v);
  }
}
```

#### The get and set methods

In get you can see how the list works (and the same concept
is used also in set and delete): we start from the begin, and 
we cross the list until we reach an element with an index equal
to the one requested. If we cannot find it we simply return 0.
If we need to "raise some sort of signal" when the value is
not found, it is easy to implement an "error callback".

As long as **sparsness** holds, searching in the whole array for an index is a good compromise in terms of memory requirements, and efficiency may be not an issue.

```
int vector_get(vector_t *v, size_t index) {
  vector_element_t * el = v->begin;
  while (el != NULL) {
    if (el->index == index)
      return el->value;
    el = el->next;
  } 
  return 0;
}

// Gosh, this set function is really a mess... I hope you can understand it...
// -.-'
size_t vector_set(vector_t *v, size_t index, int value) {
  vector_element_t * el = v->begin;
  // Case 1: Initialize the first element of the array
  if (el == NULL) {
    el = (vector_element_t *)malloc(sizeof(vector_element_t));
    if (el != NULL) {
      v->begin = el;
      v->size += 1;
      el->index = index;
      el->value = value;
      el->next = NULL;
      return v->size;
    } else {
      return 0;
    }
  }
  // Case 2: Search for the element in the array
  while (el != NULL) {
    if (el->index == index) {
      el->value = value;
      return v->size;
    }
    // Case 3: if there is no element with that index creates a new element
    if (el->next == NULL) {
      el->next = (vector_element_t *)malloc(sizeof(vector_element_t));
      if (el->next != NULL) {
        v->size += 1;
        el->next->index = index;
        el->next->value = value;
        el->next->next = NULL;
        return v->size;
      }
      return 0;
    }
    el = el->next;
  }
}
```

#### Deleting an element

With this approach it is possible to delete an element quite easily, connecting
`curr->next` to `curr->next->next`. We must though free the previous `curr->next`...

```
void vector_delete(vector_t * v, size_t index) {
  vector_element_t *curr = v->begin;
  vector_element_t *next = curr->next;

  while (next != NULL) {
    if (next->index == index) {
      curr->next = next->next;
      free(next);
      return;
    } else {
      curr = next;
      next = next->next;
    }
  }
}
```

#### An iteration function

I think this is the answer to the last part of your question,
instead passing a sequence of indexes, you pass a callback to the vector.
The callback gets and sets value in a specific index. If you want to 
operate only on some specific indexes, you may include a check in the 
callback itself. If you need to pass more data to the callback, check
the very last section.

```
void vector_each(vector_t * v, int (*f)(size_t index, int value)) {
  vector_element_t *el = v->begin;
  while (el) {
    el->value = f(el->index, el->value);
    el = el->next;
  }
}
```

### Error callback

You may want to raise some **out of bounds** error or something else. One solution is to enrich your list with function pointer that represent a callback that should be called when your user sk for an undefined element:

```
typedef struct vector {
   size_t size;
   vector_element_t *begin;
   void (*error_undefined)(vector *v, size_t index);
} vector_t
```

and maybe at the end of your `vector_get` function you may want to do something like:

```
int vector_get(vector_t *v, size_t index) {
  // [ . . .] 
  // you know at index the element is undefined:
  if (v->error_undefined)
    v->error_undefined(v, index);
  else {
    // Do something to clean up the user mess... or simply
    return 0;
  }
}
```

usually it is nice to add also an helper function to set the callback...

#### Passing user data to "each" callback

If you want to pass more data to the user callback, you may add a `void*` as last argument:

```
void vector_each(vector_t * v, void * user_data, int (*f)(size_t index, int value, void * user_data));

void vector_each(vector_t * v, void * user_data, int (*f)(size_t index, int value, void * user_data)) {
   [...]
   el->value = f(el->index, el->value, user_data);
   [...]
}
```

if the user do not need it, he can pass a wonderful `NULL`.